# Communicate between components through a service and a Subject

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-material, subject

I have a service and two components.Like a child parent relationship.

And the child component has a button with a filter function. And then the results will be shown in the parent component. I had it first without a service and was using a EventEmitter in the child component. But now I have put the api calls in a separate service. So now I want to use a subject and not a EventEmitter. But the problem is now that I don't know how to show the results in the parent component.

Time to show some code. So this is the service:

```
export class ExtendedSearchService {
  private _filterparticipantByRegistration$ = new Subject<ParticipantInfoDTO[]>();
 data = this._filterparticipantByRegistration$.asObservable();

filerByRegistration(selectedValue: any, startDate: Date): Observable<ParticipantInfoDTO[]> {
    return this.participantService
      .filterParticipantsByRegistration(1, selectedValue as any, moment(startDate).format('YYYY MM D'))
      .pipe();
  }

}
```

And the child component:

This is the button on the child component

```
 <button
        [disabled]="!buttonFilterDisabled || !selectedValue || !selectedValueOptie || !startDate || !selectedQrcode"
        mat-raised-button
        color="accent"
        class="Button"
        (click)="searchFor()"
      >
        Filter
      </button>
```

And here I am using the service in the child component:

```
searchFor() {
    if (this.selectedSearch === 'Registratie') {
      this.extendedSearchService
        .filerByRegistration(this.selectedValue, this.startDate)
        .subscribe(filterByRegistration => {
          this.filterparticipant.emit(filterByRegistration);
        });
    }
}
```

And all this works.

But now the parent component:

So in this component the results has to been shown in the grid:

```
  <app-extended-search [@searchOpen]
        (clickCloseSearch)="handleClickCloseSearch()"
        [searchExtended]="searchExpanded"
        (filterparticipant) = "applyExtendedFilter($event)"
        class="extended-search"
        [ngClass]="{expanded: searchExpanded}"
      ></app-extended-search>
```

So I will explain it. I it about this line:

```
   (filterparticipant) = "applyExtendedFilter($event)"
```

So this was in the past using a EventEmitter. But now I am using a subject in the service. So how to replace this?

and this is the js code of the Parent component:

```
applyExtendedFilter(filteredParticipants: ParticipantInfoDTO[]) {
    this.datasource.data = filteredParticipants;
}
```

And what I have to change on this piece functionality?

So in the parent template I have it like this:

```
  <app-extended-search [@searchOpen]
        (clickCloseSearch)="handleClickCloseSearch()"
        [searchExtended]="searchExpanded"
        [_filterparticipantByRegistration] = "_filterparticipantByRegistration$.asObservable()"
        class="extended-search"
        [ngClass]="{expanded: searchExpanded}"
      ></app-extended-search>
```

Then I will get this error:

> Can't bind to '_filterparticipantByRegistration' since it isn't a known property of 'app-extended-search'.

And in the parent component  I have it like this:

```
 applyExtendedFilter(filteredParticipants: ParticipantInfoDTO[]) {
    this.datasource.data = filteredParticipants;
    this.extendedSearchFilterService.filerByRegistration(this.selectedValue, this.startDate);
  }
```

Comment: app-extended-search is one of the child component?

Comment: Yes, sorry, app-extended-search is the component with the filter button

Comment: So you need to communicate between the two child components?

Comment: So the child component(extended-search) is the component with the button. And the parent component(list) is the component who has to shown the results of the filter in the template(htm view)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this is how the `Subject` works.

**Parent.Component.html**

```
<app-child [childSubject]="childSubject.asObservable()"></app-child>
```

**Parent.Component.ts**

```
@Output() childSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(true);
clickEvent(){
   this.childSubject.next(true);
}
```

**Child.Component.html**

```
<div></div>
```

**Child.Component.ts**

```
@Input() childSubject: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
this.childSubject.subscribe(res => {
  Console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: ? But why you put the subject in a component with a @ouput? This will not work in my case. Can you make an example from my code. Will be nice So using the service

Comment: Ok So can you please create a https://stackblitz.com/ ? I'll just edit those code and will come up with a solution. I have used @Ouput() to pass the value from parent to child

Answer (score 0):

The  _filterparticipantByRegistration$  is private in your service. Therefor you get this error.